# Set state after observe()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

What's the best way to set state based on the data received from `observe()`?

It seems setting state via `componentWillMount()` won't work as `observe()` runs after this and the data isn't available to set state.

I'm using the observe function as advised when using [Parse](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact)

E.g.:

```
var DragApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      activeCollection : ''
    };
  },

 observe: function() {
    return {
      collections: (collectionsQuery.equalTo("createdBy", currentUser))
    };
  },

  _setactiveCollection: function(collection) {
    this.setState({
      activeCollection : collection
    });
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    var collection = this.data.collections[0];
    this._setActiveCollection(collection);
  },

)}
```

Comment: why do you have to save it separtaly into the state when you already saved it in `this.data.collections`. Just use it in the `render` method, how it is shown in the example of your link.

Comment: @marcel I did this at first. But it seemed render is rendering before this.data has updated via observe. Therefore I wanted to update state on observe complete to update render with the correct data. This feels wrong. I'd prefer to use Parse without observe altogether atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went the wrong way about this.

I shouldn't be storing this.data into state. I can pass it into components via render.

To get round this.data not being ready before rendering, I make use of the ParseReact function pendingQueries() inside render. E.g.

```
if (this.pendingQueries().length > 0) {
    content = 'loading...'
} else {
    content = 'hello world I am' + this.data.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var DragApp = React.createClass({

    observe: function() {
        var collections = collectionsQuery.equalTo("createdBy", currentUser);
        return {
          collections: collections,
          activeCollection: collections[0]
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        // do something with this.data.collections and/or this.data.activeCollection
    },

)}
```

Comment: When I set a var based on this.data in render(), sometimes it's defined, other times it's not. It seems observe hasn't finished fetching the data, how can I make sure render updates if observe hasn't finished?

Comment: i don't know the plugin, but it seems that it will rerender automatically when the data will change. So just check, if it is `undefined`. var ac = this.data.activeCollection; if (ac == null) return null; else // render